# NuGet: How to specify the license URL during nuget pack?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget, .net-assembly

I have a .csproj file that I'd like to push to [nuget.org](http://nuget.org). At the moment, I'm doing this from the command-line via `nuget pack` and `nuget push`. Here is the `AssemblyInfo` of the project:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[assembly: AssemblyTitle("ObservableVector")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription(@"Observable Vector makes it easy to use the IObservableVector<T> interface in your Windows app.

Find us on GitHub at https://github.com/jamesqo/observable-vector")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("James Ko")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("ObservableVector")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2016")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.3.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
```

What I'd like to know is, how can I specify properties such as the license/project URL or tags when packing the project? I don't think Microsoft provides any attributes to manage things like that, so would it be possible short of creating a .nuspec file?

I've tried looking into the [command-line documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/Command-Line-Reference#pack-command) but it doesn't seem to mention tags or anything of that sort.

**TL;DR** How can I specify things like the license/project URL within the `AssemblyInfo` (or from the command-line) when creating a new NuGet package?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I tried doing this from the terminal:

```
nuget pack Foo.csproj -Prop Configuration=Release;ProjectUrl=http://the.url/
```

Unforunately it doesn't seem to be working, since when I unzip the `nupkg` and open the `nuspec`, there is no mention of the project URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently it's not possible in the current version of NuGet:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2024

I had to create a `nuspec` file.